# one of lines in matplotlib is not visualized

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, data-visualization

```
from datetime import datetime
import datetime as dt
import csv    
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ldays = list()
aesvalues = list()
tezvalues = list()
vdevalues = list()

with open('data/dg_year_50.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    has_header = csv.Sniffer().has_header(csvfile.read(1024))
    csvfile.seek(0)  # Rewind.
    datareader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    if has_header:
        next(datareader)  # Skip header row.

    for row in datareader:
        date_cell = row[0]
        aes_cell = row[1]
        tez_cell = row[2]
        vde_cell = row[3]
        datetime_object = datetime.strptime(date_cell, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
        aesvalues.append(aes_cell)
        tezvalues.append(tez_cell)
        vdevalues.append(tez_cell)
        ldays.append(datetime_object)

days = mdates.date2num(np.array(ldays))

s_aesvalues = sorted(list(map(int, aesvalues)))
s_tezvalues = sorted(list(map(int, tezvalues)))
s_vdevalues = sorted(list(map(int, vdevalues)))


# These are the colors that will be used in the plot
color_sequence = ['#ffbb78', '#e377c2', '#1f77b4', '#ff7f0e', '#2ca02c',
              '#98df8a', '#d62728', '#ff9896', '#9467bd', '#c5b0d5',
              '#8c564b', '#c49c94', '#aec7e8', '#e377c2', '#f7b6d2',
              '#c7c7c7', '#bcbd22', '#dbdb8d', '#17becf', '#9edae5']

# make a plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 12))

# plot the data
majors = [s_tezvalues, s_vdevalues, s_aesvalues]

for rank, column in enumerate(majors):
    line = plt.plot_date(x=days, y=majors[rank], lw=2.5,    color=color_sequence[rank])

fig.suptitle('Дані по енергетиці', fontsize=18, ha='center')
plt.xlabel('Дата', fontsize=14, ha='center')
plt.ylabel('Кількість енергії (Вт)', fontsize=14, ha='center')

plt.show()
```

I have 'data/dg_year_50.csv' with 4 columns (Дата,АЕС,ТЕЦ,ВДЕ).
First one stands for "Date" and rest 3 for the appropriate values that needs to be visualized as a lines in plot.
I do not understand why I'm getting visualized 2 lines instead of 3.
The result visualization looks like this:[image]

Comment: I don't know what these color sequence codes corresponds to but is there any chance that one of them corresponds to white color?

Comment: May I suggest that you use pandas instead of CSV reader? That would save you 50% of your code... Please include the first several lines of your CSV file into the question.

Comment: @Bazingaa No, all of them are non-white. White is #ffffff

Comment: Maybe there is an empty column in your csv file. Who is supposed to know that without a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake, it was in the following string:

```
vdevalues.append(tez_cell)
```

It should be changed like this:

```
vdevalues.append(vde_cell)
```

And yes, definitely, with pandas solution is much easier:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv('data/dg_year_50.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True).apply(np.int64)
data.plot()
plt.show()
```

Attaching the result figure: